# Google Map APi zoom bar not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google map api is not showing zoom bar and imagetype completely instead it is just displaying plus minus buttons for zoom in and out and drop down for selecting map type.
Url is http://booking.smanager.net/design/index.php?lv=2 please see tab "Location". I m using firefox 3.6.10. What might be the reason?

```
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
         var myOptions = {
           zoom: 8,
           center: myLatlng,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Also I want to insert placemarker at several lat/long pairs. I got title and description of several locations which I want to be displayed inside a placemarker. Can anyone tell how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens when the map that contains the div isn't sized properly.. whilst you've indicated that you're using V3 api its still something to consider.. some info here:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic19.htm

Duncan