# zoom slider doesn't appears on my google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, slider, zooming, google-maps-api-2

First of all, I've also tried with [Google Map APi zoom bar not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851198/google-map-api-zoom-bar-not-showing), but with no success at all, so I'll tell you my problem. Ok, the code is as follows:

```
var datos = '<%=coorNom%>';
var origen='<%=origen%>';
var vAPIKey = '<%=APIKey%>';
var vLangmap = '<%=langmap%>';
var mapcoords;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");      
    var gurl =   "http://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=loadMapscoord&key=" + vAPIKey + "&oe=UTF8&ie=UTF8&hl=" + vLangmap;
    script.src = gurl;                                                                          
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
});

// Se utiliza esta función para no tener que cargar cada vez el api desde google maps y ya tenerlo descargado en el cliente
function loadMapscoord(){
    setTimeout("google.load('maps', '2.x', {'callback':initMapcoord});", 100);
}

function initMapcoord(){
    window.onunload=google.maps.Unload;
    mapcoords = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("mapa"));
    mapcoords.enableDoubleClickZoom();
    mapcoords.enableContinuousZoom();
    mapcoords.enableScrollWheelZoom();

    var mapControl = new google.maps.MapTypeControl();
    mapcoords.addControl(mapControl);       
    var zoomControl = new google.maps.LargeMapControl();
    mapcoords.addControl(zoomControl);
    initializeCoords();

//  Tenemos que esperar a cargar el mapa para ocultar la capa y mostrar la info.
    if (origen == "info"){
        parent.cuerpo(origen, 'localizacion');
    }
}

function initializeCoords() {   
    mapcoords.clearOverlays();
    mapcoords.closeInfoWindow();
    mapcoords.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);    
    mapcoords.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),0);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();    
    var markers = new Array(); //Array de marcadores
    //Obtenemos la estructura de datos    
    var numcoords = datos.split('|');
    for (var x = 0; x < numcoords.length-1; x++){   
        var coord = numcoords[x].split('@')[0]; 
        var lat = coord.split('**')[0];
        var lon = coord.split('**')[1];
        if ((lat != undefined) && (lat != '') && (lon != undefined) && (lon != '')){
            markers.push({latlng: new google.maps.LatLng( parseFloat( lat ), parseFloat( lon ) ), name: numcoords[x].split('@')[1]} );
        }
    }
    //creamos los distintos marcadores y los asociamos al mapa
    for (var z in markers){
        marker = createMarker(markers[z]);
        mapcoords.addOverlay(marker);       
    }

    //Calculamos el centro y zoom adecuados para el mapcoords
    for (var i in markers){
        bounds.extend(markers[i].latlng);
    } 
    mapcoords.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), mapcoords.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds) - 7);

    if (origen == "imprimir"){
        setTimeout("parent.imprime();",300);
    }
}  

</script>
```

The problem is that I've got the map, everything works fine, but I haven't got the zoom control slider, and I need it. You can see the line with `var zoomControl = new google.maps.LargeMapControl();`, and I understand it should work, and show the slider, but "au contrair", the two button, for zoom in and out, are together, with no slider between them.

Please..., can anybody tell me how to fix it? or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.